# httpContext.User claim is not updated after passing through Custom Authentication Handler in .NET 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, authorization

I am using .Net 6 WebApi. I have a need to support dual authentication scheme. One scheme is using standard OIDC provided Access token for which I am using the standard AddJwtBearer extension method with tokenvalidation parameters. For second scheme, I have created a custom Authentication Handler using the .Net's own JwtBearerHandler.cs code as reference.

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/a450cb69b5e4549f5515cdb057a68771f56cefd7/src/Security/Authentication/JwtBearer/src/JwtBearerHandler.cs

For initial implementation, except for changing from Bearer to CustomBearer, I haven't done any other changes, so that easier to troubleshoot during initial development.

I also have some custom AuthorizationHandler classes for applying custom Authorization policies.

The problem that I am facing is that even though the authentication of the incoming JWT is happening successfully in the Custom Authentication Handler and I am setting the TokenValidateContext with the claim principle from the incoming JWT, I am not seeing httpContext.User updated with the proper identity.

Even in the Custom Authorization Handler's HandleRequirementAsync method, the AuthorizationHandlerContext does not have the authenticated user identity/principle/claim information.

I am facing this issue, only when Authentication is handled by my custom handler class. If I am passing the standard OIDC provided access_token, httpContext.User and AuthorizationHandlerContext, both reflect the authenticated user.

So i am thinking that I am missing some step in between after completing the authentication which is causing the httpContext.User not to reflect the authenticated User Principle information.

In my custom authentication handler's HandleAuthenticateAsync method, after successful validation of the token, should I simply overwrite httpContext.User with the Principle created from the token? Or is there any other standard way to update the value as the reference JwtBearerHandler.cs does not perform any such action.

Any guidance on this will be very helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add a [mre].

Comment: My custom handler code is a replica of JwtBearerHandler.cs for which I have provided the link. Except for renaming the class and changing the Authentication scheme name from Bearer to CustomBearer, there is no difference. I have not made any other customization yet.

Comment: I think a sample is better for other contributors to troubleshoot the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. The reason why I was not getting the authenticated user principle in AuthorizationHandlerContext was because when registering the policy, I had only added bearer Authentication scheme. So when the incoming JWT was being authenticated by a different authentication scheme, the identity was not being set.

This also meant that I really did not need a custom authentication handler. So I added a custom header to let me determine, which authentication scheme to use and then went back to using standard AddJwtBearer extension method that uses the inbuilt JwtBearerHandler for authentication.